# React component vis-force module error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying install react-vis-force module but not working properly.

I edited package.json to install 'react-vis-force' vs 0.3.1

But I met error.
*Cannot find module './factoryWithTypeCheckers' from node_modules/react-vis-force/dist*

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Based [on a solution found in the issues section of another react library](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/870), you can resolve this issue by changing the import statement.

```
import {ForceGraph, ForceGraphNode, ForceGraphLink} from 'react-vis-force/dist/react-vis-force.min.js';
```

The un-minified version of the code has a missing dependency- the minified version does not. It appears as though npm was using the un-minified version by default.

Answer (score -1):

If you're working with npm try to do it

```
npm install --save react-vis-force
```

With `--save` you save your dependency in `package.json`

If you have do it before, try `npm install` for reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: I'm getting this error when install that module using that command.

Comment: Try deleting your `node_modules` folder, and after that run `npm install` for install completely your node_modules again.  @Guru